# Android refresh actionbar and title on fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

in my app i am developing an activity using the actionbar in `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`-mode.
Each tab is showing a fragment (list, detail).
Initially the list-tab is visibile.
The list is implementing `setMultiChoicheModeListener()` and modifies the `ActionBar` and the title of the activity if one or more items are selected.
How can i reset the title and the `ActionBar` to the inital value (title and actions) when the user clicks on the detail-tab without deselecting the items?

BTW Target-Platform is > 4.1 and i am not using the support library.

Thanks.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.actionBar = getActionBar();
        this.actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ....
        for (Tab tab : getTabs())
        {
           //here are two tabs added (List and Detail)
           this.actionBar.addTab(tab);
        }
        ....
    }

    protected class NavigationTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

        private Fragment fragment;
        ....
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           ft.replace(newFragmentResourceId, this.fragment);
        }
    }
}

public class MyListViewFragment extends LinearLayout implements IListViewFragment {

     ....

     @Override
     public void initialize() {
         inflate(getContext(), listLayoutResourceId, this); 
         this.myList.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
         this.myList.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        ....

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(selectedItemsMenuResourceId, menu);

            return true;
        }

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
        {
            if (checked)
            {
                this.numberItemsSelected++;
                adapter.setNewSelection(position);
            }
            else
            {
                this.numberItemsSelected--;
                adapter.removeSelection(position);
            }

            mode.setTitle(getContext().getResources().getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.items_selected, this.numberItemsSelected,
                Integer.valueOf(this.numberItemsSelected)));

         }

         ....

     }
}
```

I am trying to implement the MVP pattern, but it's still in evaluation phase. The Activity acts as the presenter, the views are in separate classes.

For each Fragment i am also implementing the MVP apttern, but i think this is not interesting to solve the problem.

Some notes to the classes:

`MyActivity` creates two fragments (one for List, one for Detail view, the detail view has nothing to do with the selected items).
The initial view of the activity is the fragment with the list.
If the user selects some entries I am updating the action bar and the title through the callback of `MultiChoiceModeListener`. 
But the user can now change the fragment by clicking on the "Detail" tab without deselecting the items or clicking to the new elements in the action bar, the result is that the detail fragment is shown, but the title of the activity is still the one I modified in the `MultiChoiceModeListener`, and there is also the check mark of the action bar visible (auto created by the system).
So the best way is I think to get somehow the current `ActionMode`, so I can invoke finish() to "reset" the `ActionBar` and the title.

Comment: Perhaps a better way is possible but what first comes to mind is to re-create the actionbar, saving which items are selected and mark those during creation.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. But isn't there any possibility to get the current ActionMode from the actionbar, which you get in the callbacks. This object has a finish method doing the exact thing i want. I dont want to take care and worry about what the previous title and actionbar menu entries were.

Comment: Well, I must admit that it is not 100% clear to me what the problem is. Could you provide some code that pinpoints the problem? Cannot help but to think that the list fragment should remember the selections independant of the actionbar. Then, when selecting details you should be able to modify the actionbar back to its initial state, just as you were able to modify it when selecting items, or am I missing something? I can see in my code that I have just settled with re-creating the actionbar when I needed to add/remove tabs or the like but it is also a rare event in my app.

Comment: I have provided code and tried to explain the issue again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you keep reference of the `ActionMode` in the `ActionMode.Callback` methods inside your activity which has the `ActionBar.TabListener`.
When a new tab is selected just finish the action mode, like:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           if(mActionMode != null){
              mActionMode.finish();
           }
           ft.replace(newFragmentResourceId, this.fragment);

 }
```

Make the `ActionMode` reference back to null when `onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode)` is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out and it works, but is there any approach without creating members?

Comment: After a couple of time i investigated to solve the problem i couldn't find any other solution than this approach with the reference, it solves my problem although i am not happy with it. Thanks.

Comment: How does keeping ActionMode member not fit your case?

Comment: As i mentioned it solves the problem. But the framework could do this for me,too since with the back button or with the check mark it recovers the previous state of the ActionBar and the title, so i think it calls finish() to the current ActionMode.